# What if a Poké Ball was lost and couldn't be opened?

Tags: pokemon

I was reading a [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4947/18881) on what it is like inside of a Poké Ball. It made me wonder what will happen to a Pokémon if the Poké Ball is lost or damaged. If the Poké Ball was unable to open, would they simple die?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There have been several instances in the show where a Pokémon was in its Poké Ball for a long time, such as in [*Sandshrew's Locker*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP047). In this episode, Ash and friends helped Mira recover Sandshrew's Poké Ball from the bottom of the lake, where it's been for a long time. Additionally, Mira and her friends discovered Sandshrew's Poké Ball themselves. In the episode [*Two Degrees of Separation!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP002) James found his Carnivine's Poké Ball inside a box containing one of his bottle cap collections, where he left it as a child. So, the precedents in the show indicate that Pokémon can survive a long time unattended in their Poké Ball, though it is unclear as to why since how the Pokéballs work is not well explained.

Comment: Perhaps when inside the pokeball, the pokemons are in cyrosleep state

Comment: If we go with the idea that Pokémon get save digitally to the PC for storage, it isn't much of a stretch to save Pokémon at specific points in time that get loaded again when their Pokéball re-opens

Comment: @Gorp except in the anime Pokémon aren't stored in the PC like in the games, instead they are sent to the person who gave that trainer their Pokédex (usually the regional professor) so that they can take care of it for them.